# PHP & MySQL: How do I compare the user input to data in the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a HTML form with a textbox where you enter a username, and a login button. When the user presses the login button, I want the database to be queried and if there is a match echo out a statement. The code I have is this:

```
<form class="login_box" method="POST">
        <input id="input-boxes1" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
        <input id="button-1" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>


// Checks if login button is pressed
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
      $enteredUser = $_POST['username'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$enteredUser'";
      if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
          echo 'it works';
      }
    }
```

What I want it to do is echo out "it works" if there is a match. However it always echoes it out no matter what. The database is working as intended as I have added to it and selected from it in other files, and the database is correctly linked to this form as well.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: The only time it won't echo the message is when the query fails to run (not finding a match does not qualify as failing). You should check how many rows were selected.

Comment: Aside from that, it seems like you're only learning. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and, while it might seem overwhelming at first, you'll be better off starting to learn `PDO` with prepared, parametrized queries. Here's a good [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Comment: @El_Vanja Ah ok that does make sense I guess. Is there a way to have it so that it only echoes out if there's a match? I also used    echo "Returned rows are: " . mysqli_num_rows($result);   which returned the correct number of rows when a valid username was entered and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Yes, of course. Check to see how many rows your query returns. For a successful login it should return exactly one row.

Comment: @droopsnoot So should I have an if statement that checks if the number of returned rows is 1, and if so echo out the statement?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @El_Vanja and @droopsnoot for helping. I've managed to figure out the solution now. As they rightly pointed out, I had to see if the number of rows returned was 1 and then echo out the statement if so.

My amended code is as below:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
      $enteredUser = $_POST['username'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$enteredUser'";
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
          echo 'it works';
      }
}
```

Comment: Glad it's working. Now you need to read up on "Prepared Statements" as @El_Vanja commented above, rather than concatenating strings into your query.